# Swift app other processes eating up all RAM memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm developing an iOS Video Player app and i have 3 View Controllers. First one (VC1) have a collection view with a header that contains a carousel with pictures in a horizontal scroll view, the second one (VC2) contains a collection view with header that contains an image and the third one (VC3) is the player.

The problem appears when i switch for many times (let's say 10) between VC1 and VC2, because the "Other Processes" from Debug Navigator is growing without dropping any considerable amount of RAM memory, every time when i'm loading VC2.

Statistics after the app has been opened:[image: Statistics after the app has been opened:]

Statistics after I open VC2 for 7 times (2-3 more and it crashed = i lost the connection between Xcode and my iPad) :[image: Statistics after I open VC2 for 7 times (2-3 more and it crashed = i lost the connection between Xcode and my iPad) :]

I can't figure out why this happens because i pop VC2 every time i come back to VC1.

Thank you!

Comment: @vikingosegundo thank you for edit :D

Comment: @vikingosegundo why have you rejected my edit, while I am following something [considered right](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267384/removing-someone-elses-thank-you)

Comment: yes, just deleting "Thank you" is not an improvement what so ever. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267386/106435

Comment: The the other answer: what you do is problematic. Just deleting what most of us don't consider harmful, you are filling edit queues, waste other people time review this. You can delete or not such a sentence in a broader edit. but if it is the only change it creates more noise in the system than just leaving it. Try rot get your reputation from answering stuff. nit from doing mass.edits.

Comment: @tod: try to get to 2000 by answering questions, not to make useless edits that will keep other people occupied.

Comment: @vikingosegundo useful advice, however, use of impolite words won't make the opinion any louder. I think following the broader majority is the right way to go. Thanks

Comment: @vikingosegundo http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions/260778#260778

Comment: As I said. remove it, but don't make it review only this. If it is part of a bigger edit, it is ok. if not it is an annoyance. Speaking of impoliteness: annoy people is impolite.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Well both opinions are there, I prefer the otherwise and consider that, it does not cause any annoyance but is otherwise. Using impolite words is definitely impolite.

Comment: What words do u consider impolite?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, AVAssets and likely many other framework classes provided by Apple aren't included in the memory usage for your application when run in your actual device.

My guess is the memory is allocated by some other process internally.

Your application is, however, still blamed for the leaked memory when iOS decides to kill offending apps.

Are you sure you weren't keeping references to all previous AVAssets and similar objects?

If you run the same software in the simulator you should see a clearly leaking graph.